# Radon Nikodym property (Banach valued) is separably determined $\sigma-$finite case

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Im reading Analysis in Banach spaces (https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319485195) and I was trying to provide a different demostration of lemma 1.3.17, which is used in order to prove that the Radon Nikodym property is separably determined (theorem 1.3.18). The lemma says:
Suppose that X has the RNP with respect to a $\sigma-$finite measure space $(S,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a sub$-\sigma-$algebra of $\mathcal{A}$ . Then X has the RNP
with respect to $(S,\mathcal{B},\mu_{\restriction{\mathcal{B}}})$.
They prove it using results of other section, so I would like to prove it in a self-contained form.
Modifying a finite version from these lectures notes (http://wwwarchive.math.psu.edu/huff/ , chapter 7, lemma 7.5.1) it's easy to prove it if the sub$-\sigma-$algebra is $\sigma-$finite:
Lemma:
Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite measure space. For every sub$-\sigma-$algebra $\Sigma_0$ of $\Sigma$ there exists a unique function $E_0: \mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu,X)\longmapsto \mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu_{\restriction{\Sigma_0}},X)$ such that
$$\displaystyle\int_{A}f d\mu = \displaystyle\int_{A} (E_0 f) d\mu$$ for every $A\in\Sigma_0$ and every $f\in \mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu,X).$ In addition, $E_0$ it's a  bounded and linear operator of $||E_0||\leq1.$

Unicity follows from previous result. Let $A\in\Sigma$ be fixed, then the map $E \longmapsto \mu(A\cap E)$ with $E\in\Sigma_0,$ defines a finite positive measure $\Sigma_0$ which is absolute continuous with respect $\mu_{\restriction{\Sigma_0}}.$ By Radon-Nikodym theorem there exists a $g_A \in \mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu_{\restriction{\Sigma_0}})$ such that
$$\mu(A\cap E)=\displaystyle\int_{E}g_A d\mu \hspace{0.2cm} \text{ for all } E\in\Sigma_0.$$ For a simple function $f=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_j \chi_{A_j},$ we define
$$E_0(f)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_j g_{A_j}.$$ It's easy to see that $E_0$ it's linear and continuous over the simple functions with $||E_0||\leq1$ and that $\displaystyle\int_{E}f d\mu = \displaystyle\int_{E} (E_0 f) d\mu$ for all $E\in\Sigma_0.$ Therefore it admits a unique externsion to a bounded and linear operator $E_0:\mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu,X) \longmapsto\mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu_{\restriction{\Sigma_0}},X)$ with $||E_0||\leq1.$ If $f_n$ it's a sequence of simple functions such that $||f_n-f||_1 \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$ for $f\in \mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu,X),$ thens $||E_0f_n-E_0f||_1 \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$ and for all $E\in\Sigma_0$
$$\displaystyle\int_{E}(E_0 f)d\mu = \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\int_{E}(E_0 f_n)d\mu=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\int_{E}f_n d\mu=\displaystyle\int_{E}f d\mu.$$

Also I know that if $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a $\sigma-$finite measure space and $\mathcal{B}$ is a sub$-\sigma-$algebra, we can find a disjoint decomposition $\Omega=S_0 \cup S_1$ such that the restriction of $\mu$  to $\mathcal{B}_{\restriction{S_0}}$  is $\sigma-$finite and the restriction of $\mu$ to $\mathcal{B}_{\restriction{S_1}}$ is purely infinite.
I doubt that it's possible, because the authors would have done it, but I have to prove theorem 1.3.18, and this lemma is used, so I need to prove it. Other solution would be see the way it's used in the theorem and see if I need to prove something easier only; in fact i think we can assume the sub$-\sigma-$algebra is countably generated, but cant see how that helps. Anyway, any comments would help. Thanks a lot in advance.